# Сервис для получения названия населенного пункта по его координатам

Tags: visual-studio, геолокация, веб-служба, windows-phone-7

Есть долгота и широта, подскажите наиболее удобный сервис, чтоб в итоге я получил название населенного пункта этих координат.

Пишу для Windows Phone.
удобный для этого был сервис http://msrmaps.com/terraservice2.asmx но он не работает :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) не смотрели? С [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) можно без проблем получить информацию о населенном пункте по координатам. Даже адрес примерный. Ответы можно получать как в JSON так и в XML.